# How to make my object methods globally accessible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a voip project. I have 2 pages, one page is for making outgoing calls, the other page is only for receiving calls.

Im using an external js file where I define a few object methods so I can access them everywhere in my component.

**Problems:**

- I'm using the same file for both receiving calls and making
  outgoing calls.(My object methods should do different things based on
  the type of call)
- I have to manipulate my HTML using javascript from within that object.

**What I want:**

- I would like to have my object methods globally accessible from
  within my component.
- **Able to manipulate the state within my object methods so I could re-render**

**My external js file** (My voip client will call these listeners automatically)

```
var callListeners = {
    onCallProgressing: function (call) {
        audioProgress.src = './style/ringback.wav';
        audioProgress.loop = true;
        audioProgress.play();

        //Report call stats
        $('div#callLog').append('<div id="stats">Ringing...</div>');
    },
    onCallEstablished: function (call) {
        audioIncoming.srcObject = call.incomingStream;
        audioIncoming.play();
        audioProgress.pause();
        audioRingTone.pause();

        //Report call stats
        var callDetails = call.getDetails();
        $('div#callLog').append('<div id="stats">Answered at: ' + (callDetails.establishedTime && new Date(callDetails.establishedTime)) + '</div>');
    },
    onCallEnded: function (call) {
        audioProgress.pause();
        audioRingTone.pause();
        audioIncoming.srcObject = null;
        if($('button#takeCall')) {

            $('button#takeCall').addClass('d-none');
            $('button#refuseCall').addClass('d-none');
        }
        //Report call stats
        var callDetails = call.getDetails();
        $('div#callLog').append('<div id="stats">End cause: ' + call.getEndCause() + '</div>');
        if (call.error) {
            $('div#callLog').append('<div id="stats">Failure message: ' + call.error.message + '</div>');
        }
    }
}
```

**My component**

```
class Recipient extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            name: null,
            user: 'a User',
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.CreateAccount();
    }
    CreateAccount() {
        const name = this.state.user;
        axios
            .post("/api/auth", { name })
            .then(res => { sinchClient.start(res.data).then(() => this.handleSuccess()); })
            .catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
    }
    answerCall(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        call.answer();
        console.log(callListeners);
    }
    hangUpCall(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        call && call.hangup();
        console.log(call.getDetails());
    }
    handleSuccess() {
        console.log('ready to receive incoming calls!')
    }
    renderCallArea() {
        let callArea;
        callArea =
            <div className="frame">
                <div id="call">
                    <form id="newCall">
                        <button id="takeCall" className="ml-2 btn btn-light d-none" onClick={(e) => this.answerCall(e)}>Opnemen</button>
                        <button id="refuseCall" className="ml-2 btn btn-dark d-none" onClick={(e) => this.hangUpCall(e)}>Weigeren</button>
                        <button id="leaveCall" className="ml-2 btn btn-dark d-none" onClick={(e) => this.hangUpCall(e)}>Verlaat gesprek</button>
                        {/* <button id="answer" onClick={(e) => this.answerCall(e)}>Answer</button> */}
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className="clearfix"></div>
                <div id="callLog">
                </div>
                <div className="error">
                </div>
            </div>;

        return callArea;
    }
    render() {
        const wrapperStyle = {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(127, 130, 160)',
            minHeight: '600px',
        }
        const jumboStyle = {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(109, 113, 152)',
            color: 'white',
            borderRadius: '0'
        }

        return (
            <div className="wrapper" style={wrapperStyle}>
                <div className="jumbotron" style={jumboStyle}>
                    <h1 className="text-center">Wachten op een gesprek...</h1>
                </div>
                <div className='container mt-2'>
                    {this.renderCallArea()}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Recipient;
```

Any tips on how I should achieve this?

Comment: Can you transform your object methods into a class, and pass that instance from the app level down to your child components? They would be sharing the same instance. They would also be global if you manually pass them as props to child components that requires it.

Comment: Would I be able to trigger a render from this class on to my child component? For example I want to return new elements when `onCallProgressing` gets fired. If this is the case, can you show me this in an example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't 100% know what you mean by external js file, but I would extract that into your react app as an import. This is what it would look like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class External {
  static onCallProgressing () {
    // Do some action...
    return <div>{ `Ringing...` }</div>
  }
}

class App extends Component {

  callExternal() {
    return External.onCallProgressing()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        { this.callExternal() }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

If you need to pass the value of the function to the child:

You first declare a state:

```
state = {
  data
}
```

Set the state after calling the external function

```
callExternal() {
  this.setState({ data: External.onCallProgressing() })
}
```

Have the child receive props from the state:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyChild data={ this.state.data } />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Have the child render the props:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      { this.props.data }
    </div>
  );
}
```